# Not Implemented Error During Registration

Tags: django, forms, registration

I'm trying to salt the password before it is inserted into the database.  I've overridden the save method but I'm getting a "NotImplementedError".  What am I doing wrong?

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from users.models import User

class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def save(self, user):
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
        user.save()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

`views.py`

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(request.user)
                return HttpResponse('User created succcessfully.')
        else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()

        context = {}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        context['form'] = form
        return render_to_response('/', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should rather look like this:

```
def save(self):
    user = super(UserRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```

As far as I know Django has a built-in view for user registration so there's no need of writing your own (except from learning).

Answer (score 0):

I think your import is using the default view instead of the one from a backend that has been implemented.

```
from registration.backends.hmac.views import RegistrationView
```

Instead of from registration.views import RegistrationView